# Printing an array list of objects

Tags: java

I am trying to do some practice Java. Right now I am doing exercises from a textbook for fun and I am stuck on one problem. This particular problem requires me to create a class called "Purse" and then create "Coins" which can be added to a given purse. This part I have been able to do. The last part of the exercise is to print the purse by using a toString method. I will show my classes below.

Purse

```
package exercisePurse;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Purse {

    private ArrayList<Coin> coins;

    public Purse(){

        coins = new ArrayList<Coin>();

    }

    public void addCoin(Coin a){

        coins.add(a);

    }

    public String getCoins(){

        String allCoins = coins.toString();

        return allCoins;

    }

}
```

Coin

```
package exercisePurse;

public class Coin 

{

    String coin;
    int value;

    public Coin(String coinName, int coinValue){

        coin = coinName;
        value = coinValue;

    }

}
```

Tester class

```
package exercisePurse;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CoinTester 

{

    public static void main(String args[]){

        Purse purse1 = new Purse();
        purse1.addCoin(new Coin("Quarter", 2));
        purse1.addCoin(new Coin("Dime", 3));
        purse1.addCoin(new Coin("Nickle", 4));
        purse1.addCoin(new Coin("Penny", 10));

        System.out.println(purse1.getCoins());

    }

}
```

Results of a run

```
[exercisePurse.Coin@2a139a55, exercisePurse.Coin@15db9742, exercisePurse.Coin@6d06d69c, exercisePurse.Coin@7852e922]
```

Specifically I know my problem area is here

```
public String getCoins(){

        String allCoins = coins.toString();

        return allCoins;

    }
```

What I want is for the purse to display the coin names and values. So something like this:

purse1[Quarters 2, Dimes 3, Nickles 2, Pennies 5]

Any help is appreciated, sorry if this has been asked before because I know there are posts on using toString I just couldn't figure out how to implement a solution in this case.

EDIT:

I need to specifically follow these instructions to consider the exercise complete:

```
Implement a class Purse. A purse contains a collection of coins. For simplicity, we
will only store the coin names in an ArrayList<String>. (We will discuss a better representation
in Chapter 8.) Supply a method
void addCoin(String coinName)
Add a method toString to the Purse class that prints the coins in the purse in the
format
Purse[Quarter,Dime,Nickel,Dime]
```

Comment: I don't see that you overwrote the toString() method for the ArrayList?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, sounds like you know how to fix could you explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is printing the reference of the `Coin` object and not the value. What you have to do is either:

1. Override the `toString()` method on the `Coin`.

   ```
   public String getCoins(){
       String allCoins = coins.toString();
       return allCoins;
   }

   public class Coin {
       private String coin;
       private int value;

       public Coin(String coinName, int coinValue){
           this.coin = coinName;
           this.value = coinValue;
       }

       public String toString(){
           return this.coin + " " + String.valueOf(this.value);
       }

       /* Getter-Setters */
   }
   ```
2. Or iterate the list and prepare the result String:

   ```
   public String getCoins() {
       /* Assuming you include `purseName` member in the purse class for storing purse name */
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(this.purseName + "[");
       for(Coin c : coins) {
           sb.append(c.getCoin() + " " + c.getValue() + ", ");
       }
       return sb.append("]").toString();
   }
   ```

---

Tip: You *should* use the `getter-setters` for getting and setting the class members.
Alternatively, you can set the visibility to `public` if you are not using the `getter-setters`.

Comment: May I know why this has been down-voted?

Comment: I did not down vote but I'd like to add that your solution does work but the text describes it like this: "Add a method toString to the Purse class that prints the coins in the purse in the
format
Purse[Quarter,Dime,Nickel,Dime]"

Can you give a solution that meets that format, that is what I'm having trouble with.

Comment: why change the modifier to `public`?

Comment: @jesric1029 Please check the updated solution.

Comment: (not downvoter) don't agree with publicity here (Coin/Purse in the same package), plus using getter/setter is best practice. Also, direct `StringBuilder/Buffer` usage is outdated, afaik, modern compilators can automatically optimize in-loop string concatenations by themself. Also, premature optimization is premature optimization... Suggesting simple `String r = ""; for (Coint c: coins) r += (r.isEmpty() ? "" : ", ") + coin.coin + " " + coin.value; return "[" + r + "]";` or alike as alternative.

Comment: Thanks. It printed in this format "Quarter Dime Nickle Penny " The directions stated it needed to print in the format where the name of the purse is first like this "purse1[quarter dime nickle penny]" if you know how to add this part let me know but I'll still mark as answered.

Comment: If you overriding `toString()` in `Coin`, then `toString()` in Purse can just contain `sb.append(c.toString())`, but direct `StringBuilder` usage will be completely useless. Either don't override `toString()` in `Coin`, or don't bother with builder...

Comment: @jesric1029, use my example in comment previous to yours, but 1) add `name` property to `Purse` 2) allow to pass name to purse via purse object constructor 3) change return statement in `Purse.toString()` to `return name + " [" + r + "]";`

Comment: @ankhzet I written this answer in bit of a hurry and was not thinking about the *Most Optimized Code*. Well I agree with some of your points but still I don't prefer doing `r += ...` for Strings are immutable. What is the problem in using a StringBuilder/StringBuffer?

Comment: The problem is quite the same as with reimplementing quicksort - to much redundant code for zero gain. Using `StringBuilder` for simple concatenation is just an overkill. What the point to avoid direct string concatenation and then just write `sb.append(c.getCoin() + " " + c.getValue() + ", ");`? Either don't use concatenation (`sb.append(c.getCoin()).append(" ").append(c.getValue()).append(", ");` as in most java native sources with builder usage), or not use builder at all, and leave possible optimizations to compiller, as builder in such a trivial usecase is a premature optimization.

Comment: `for Strings are immutable` - `String`s - are, function result variable - not.

Answer (score 1):

As [there](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toString()) say:when you call List.toString(),it will print out the element.toString() one by one,but you didn't custom the method for this element:`Coin` object,so its address is print out.

To make what you want,just implement `toString()` method for your `Coin` class,like this:

```
public class Coin {
    String coin;
    int value;

    public Coin(String coinName, int coinValue){
        coin = coinName;
        value = coinValue;
    }

    public String toString(){
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        sb.append("coinName=");
        sb.append(this.coin);
        sb.append(";");
        sb.append("value=");
        sb.append(this.value);
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Coin{
    String coin;
    int value;

    public Coin(String coinName, int coinValue){
        coin = coinName;
        value = coinValue;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("Coin name:").append(this.coin).append(",")
        .append("Coin value:").append(this.value);

        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

When you get your coins from purse, iterate the list and print out all coins information.

```
ArrayList<Coins> coins = purse1.getCoins();

for(Coin coin: coins){
    System.out.println(coin.toString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

override the toString() method on Coin

```
public String toString() {
    return coin + "s" + value;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

All "non-primitive" data types come with a `to[TYPE]()` method for their primitive "equivalent". (`toString()`, `toDouble()`, `toInteger()`, etc.)

With this, it will be "transformed" on the spot to return certain information.

For example, lets say you have this class.

```
public class Foo{
   private String _foo = "bar";  
   private int foobar = 0;
   public String toString(){
      return _foo;
   }
   public Integer toInteger(){
      return foobar;
   }
}

public class FooBar{
   public static void main(){
      Foo bar;
      System.out.println(bar);
      Integer z = 5 + bar;
      System.out.println(z);
    }

}
```

A call on main will write

```
bar
 5
```

This can be done with any class, and in (nearly) any situation.

Add a `to[TYPE]()` method and return the data you want/need to return.

Essentially, what you would do for this case would be

```
public class FOOBAR{
   public static void main(){
   java.util.ArrayList<Foo>baz;
   Foo bar;
   Foo foobar;
   baz.add(bar);
   baz.add(foobar)
      for(Foo f : baz){
         System.out.println(f);

      } 
   }
}
```

A call on main will output

```
bar
bar
```